# Lock UIView position relatively to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uikit

I am trying to create an interface that shows a floor plan with markers in fixed positions so when user zooms or scrolls the floor plan, markers stay on the same position relative to floor plan image.

So far I tried to do it with a UIScrollView that holds an UIImageView and then I tried to add some dummy subview

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 200), size: CGSize(width: 36, height: 36)))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
scrollView.addSubview(view)
```

but origin (in my example 400,200) is relative to screen, which means that the dummy subview shows only when you zoom enough and then slides along if you scroll around.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Maybe I should use some other UIKit classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

- create a container view of the preferred size
- add the image view as a subview of this container view
- add you dummy subview in the container view
- from the zoom delegate method of the school view return the container view

The fact is that they need a common ancestor view

Comment: Thanks, that was so obvious. Do you happen to know if there is any way to make those "dummy" views appear the same size regardless of zoom level, other than calculating their size and position every time user zooms in or out?

Comment: I think that in the delegate method of the zoom you can apply a transform equal but with negative sign than the one applied to your content view

Comment: Actually I had to divide original size by zoom scale to keep the absolute size equal. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction. For future reference, this code does it:

`func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
var frame: CGRect!  = innerView.frame
let center = innerView.center
frame.size = CGSize(width: basicMarkerSize/scrollView.zoomScale, height: basicMarkerSize/scrollView.zoomScale)
innerView.frame = frame
innerView.center = center
}`